# Probability of answering question in an exam

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the time that takes for a student to answer a question, in minutes $X$ is:

[image]

If a student answers $35$ questions, what is the probability that the average time to answer all of those questions will be at most $20$ minutes?

So I tried to integrate on $1/40$ and on $a$ to add it up to 1. Do I need to do the integrate till $20$? And then the answer is $a$ itself? since it's between $20$ and $60$.

Comment: Never post unsearchable figures.  Instead, typeset your question in *MathJax*.

Comment: It doesn't seem easy to find $P(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_{35}}{35}\le 20)$. Are you sure this is the right question for the exam?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)dx
&= \int_0^{60}f_X(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^{20} f_X(x)dx+\int_{20}^{60} f_X(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^{20} \frac{dx}{40}+\int_{20}^{60}a\space dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+40a
\end{align}$$
Because the integral of a probability distribution should always add up to $1$, you have that $1/2+40a=1$ and therefore $a=1/80$.

Now are you able to solve the rest of the problem?

Comment: Thanks!! So If the question asking for at most 20 minutes, can I just do $1-1/80$? since it's in the range